# Yarn install in Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, yarnpkg, docker-image

I have written a Docker file and I am installing Yarn in the container. But the `yarn install/npm install` doesn't seem to work. But when I run the `yarn install` outside the Docker file, it works completely fine. I have done the required proxy settings and everything but still no success.. Not sure why it's failing.

```
FROM nexus.corportation.com:8221/nodejs:latest
ARG SRCDIR

RUN mkdir /home/nodejs/app
RUN chown -R nodejs:nodejs /home/nodejs
#Ensure correct ownership
COPY $SRCDIR /home/nodejs/app/
USER root
RUN chown -R nodejs:nodejs /home/nodejs/app
#our user setup in the base container
USER nodejs

#Now using yarn
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc;cd app;  yarn install'
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "app/javascript/index.js"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

But I get the following error:

> error An unexpected error occurred: "https://nexus.corportation.com:8221/nexus/repository/npm-all/@xyz%2flt-navigator: 
>   tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80".

This works fine outside Docker. I have tried to set the HTTP proxy along with Docker build but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the proxy in the docker file.
Check what's the default docker network its using, that network should have access to the repo.
ENV http_proxy
ENV https_proxy
ENV HTTP_PROXY
ENV HTTPS_PROXY